# How to extract part of a string in batch with a specified offset?

Tags: batch-file, extract

I am stuck of finding how to extract a CRC from a string(the offset of CRC on that string is variable) i tried to use the "0x" as a delims but it doesn't wotk
here is an example "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx0x112C8B44xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? `for /f "delims=0x" %a in ("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx0x112C8B44xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") do echo %a` gives me exactly `112C8B44`.

Comment: it is not generic try with this input string "Xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx+xxx-00.00-0x112C8B44-xxxx.99.99.xxx"

Comment: Well, others can only reply on the information you provide, so when you supply some random example data rather than realistic ones, any suggestions are not going to be helpful for you; moreover, when you continue with changing the example every time somebody tries to help you, they will eventually give up. So please provide sufficient information and realistic examples, together with a [mcve] of your own coding attempts, by [edit]ing your question! Also take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Hint: since it seems `0x` occurs only once, try to strip off everything up to this partial string, then use `for /F` with a set of delimiters that cover all characters that can follow the string portion you want to extract…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of the string isn't very clear, so I have to include some assumptions:

- there is just one occurrence of `0x`
- the length of the desired substring is always 8 characters.

.

```
set "string=some-string_12:34and0xABCDEFGHplus_some:more123chars"
set "string=%string:*0x=%" & REM remove everything until (including) '0x'
set "string=%string:~0,8%" & REM take eight chars
echo %string%
```